# What is the gitignore pattern to exclude a nested folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following folders in a project:

```
/wwwroot/lib/blue-imp-fileupload
/wwwroot/lib/jquery
/wwwroot/lib/foundation-sites
/wwwroot/lib/font-awesome
/wwwroot/lib/daily/dist
```

and want to ignore all folders EXCEPT /wwwroot/lib/daily/dist and any sub-folders and files. What would be the gitignore pattern to achieve this?

Comment: There are tons of answers for this in this platform. Please use search

Comment: Why is your git root `/` and not `/wwwroot/lib/daily/dist/`? Since you want to ignore everything but this folder I don't see any reason to begin versioning from `/`.

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer here : [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

In your `.gitignore`, add:

```
wwwroot/*
!wwwroot/lib/
wwwroot/lib/*
!wwwroot/lib/daily/
wwwroot/lib/daily/*
!wwwroot/lib/daily/dist/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/wwwroot/lib/blue-imp-fileupload
/wwwroot/lib/jquery
/wwwroot/lib/foundation-sites
/wwwroot/lib/font-awesome
```

so the  **/wwwroot/lib/daily/dist**  will be there. just don't include that path in your **.gitignore** .
I have tested this pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this will work. However, it requires hard coding all the folders to be ignored. Since these folders can change I'd rather have an exclusion for /daily so any new folders would automatically be ignored. I've experimented w/ various !/daily excludes but haven't found the solution yet.